# PHP Google_Auth_Exception: "Wrong recipient" when using Google API PHP client

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

Upon trying to use `verifyIdToken()` in the Google API PHP client, I get the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Wrong recipient, **API KEY OMMITED FOR LENGTH**.apps.googleusercontent.com != :' in C:\includes\gplus\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:621
Stack trace:
#0 C:\includes\gplus\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php(497): Google_Auth_OAuth2->verifySignedJwtWithCerts('**TOKEN OMMITED**', Array, '', Array)
#1 C:\includes\gplus\src\Google\Client.php(482): Google_Auth_OAuth2->verifyIdToken('**TOKEN OMMITED**')
#2 C:\tjWEB\googlesignin\token.php(8): Google_Client->verifyIdToken('**TOKEN OMMITED**')
#3 {main}
   thrown in C:\includes\gplus\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 621
```

My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once 'C:/includes/gplus/src/Google/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My Application");
$client->setDeveloperKey("**TOKEN OMMITED**");

var_dump($client->verifyIdToken($_POST["idtoken"]));
?>
```

And the page that calls it is available [here](https://www.techjunk.co.uk/googlesignin/index.php). I'm assuming everyone who could possibly be reading this knows how to view source code in their browser of choice.

I can't find any solutions to this on Google, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out what was causing this problem.

I needed to add

```
$client->setAuthConfigFile('C:/includes/client_secret.JSON');
```

to the PHP code which gave it my secret API key. You can download your key [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_), if you don't already have it.

**TL;DR I messed up by not reading the docs**